# How to set different colors for different lines of text in a Flutter textfield?

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

[image]

I am trying to create a text bot where I need the output of the bot to be in a different color. And I need the text to be editable so it needs to be in a textfield.
Currently when I receive the output I set the textfield text with the updated output.

Code for TextField:

```
 child: TextField(
                  controller: textFieldController,
                  expands: true,
                  maxLines: null,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter prompt',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.darkText,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Code for setting TextField text

```
conversationList.add(output);
conversation = conversationList.join("");
textFieldController.clear();
textFieldController.text = conversation;
```

I have tried packages like [detectable_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/detectable_text_field) but it would not work because the output changes.

Answer (score 1):

I ***think*** you can only use a rich text editor. Try using the [`flutter_quill`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) package.

Comment: I considered that option. I was hoping there would be a simpler way to do it but I guess not